# Equivalent of SqlFunctions in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

What is the equivalent of `SqlFunctions` in Entity Framework (EF) Core 2.0?

I am trying to convert this to EF Core

```
private static readonly MethodInfo StringConvertMethodDouble = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new Type[] { typeof(double?) });
```

**Edit #1:**
I should specify that I am generating a dynamic linq query with expression tree to query the database

Thanks

Comment: since `StringConvert` is in question, is doing `ToList()` on your LINQ query so you can use `ToString()` on objects an option?

Comment: No equivalent so far.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

EF Core surfaces functions via `EF.Functions`, however in 2.0 only `Like` is available:

```
ctx.TestEntities.Any(entity => EF.Functions.Like(entity.Name, "%foo%"))
```

Comment: That doesn't help this particular problem at all.

Comment: @alexb that's the correct answer. `EF.Functions` or rather the [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-2.1) instance returned by it  *is* the equivalent of SqlFunctions. In EF Core 2.1 most functions are available

Comment: @Martin Ullrich @Pannagiotis Anyway to invoke `Select GetDate()`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanvos do you know if Checksum has been implemented anywhere in EF.Core?